# Why the SpringBoot website refuses clients' connection after several minutes of the Jmeter load test begins?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jmeter

It is a SpringBoot website and deployed in one Linux server. We use Jmeter to do the load test.

We mock 500 users to visit the webiste index page simultaneously. The index page is very simple html, no database connection,so it is a quite short connection.

After about 2 minutes, Jmeter starts to throw timeout exception as bleow

[image]

I guess this is because of website reaching its capacity  and running out of connection.

I get one quesiton here, why does website reach its capacity 2 minutes later after Jemter starts. If its TCP connection capacity for this website is 1000, I guess it will reach 1000 very soon after the Jmeter starts, not 2 minutes.

Besides, I see many TCP connections are in TIME_WAIT status in Linux server. I guess this may be related with the connection timeout?

Edit: Someone thinks it is running of port. Someone thinks it is running out of connection. And someone thinks it is running out of processing thread(eg. [What does this messge java.net.ConnectException/Connection timed out mean in log.jtl file of Jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41582451/what-does-this-messge-java-net-connectexception-connection-timed-out-mean-in-log?rq=1)). I don't know which one is the exact reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably this is due to underlying Linux [TCP/IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) kernel stack configuration, as per [Linux TCP/IP tuning for scalability](http://www.lognormal.com/blog/2012/09/27/linux-tcpip-tuning/) article:

> By default, a connection is supposed to stay in the TIME_WAIT state for twice the msl. Its purpose is to make sure any lost packets that arrive after a connection is closed do not confuse the TCP subsystem (the full details of this are beyond the scope of this article, but ask me if you’d like details). The default msl is 60 seconds, which puts the default TIME_WAIT timeout value at 2 minutes. Which means you’ll run out of available ports if you receive more than about 400 requests a second, or if we look back to how nginx does proxies, this actually translates to 200 requests per second. Not good for scaling.

SO double check timeouts along with maximum number of ports/sockets/files on the Linux server - my expectation is that the aforementioned parameters need to be tuned for high loads.

It's also a good practice to have monitoring of baseline OS health metrics in place (CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, swap usage, etc.). You can use i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) or [JMeter SSHMon Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-monitor-server-resource-utilization-with-jmeters-sshmon-listener) for this.

Comment: Hi, Dmitri, "Which means you’ll run out of available ports if you receive more than about 400 requests a second", how does this come? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Dmitri, I googled some opinion and add it in my post. What do you think about that?

Comment: I mark this as answer. The reason why it will wait for several miniuts to throw out timeout exception is that Jmeter has a ramp up time. Not all threads are generated imediately after Jemter starts. The threads come into world by batch. After 2 miniutes, the user number accumulated to the level that the website cannot handle perfectly.